# Why does docker-compose exec only work on some services?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, sh

I have a docker-compose file specifying multiple services such as application, server, redis and database. When I want to access them I do `docker-compose exec application bash` or `docker-compose exec server bash`. But when I do a `docker-compose exec redis sh` I get the error `ERROR: No such service: redis`. I can however access it by doing `docker exec -it smb-redis sh` instead. What's the difference? Why can I access some of my running services, but not others using that command?

Comment: because docker-compose depends on its context (current directory and docker-compose.yml). To see what containers are available, run `docker-compose ps`

Answer (score 9):

service name and image name could be different. I could have a below `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
mysql:
  image: redis
```

And then to get into redis I will need to use

```
docker-compose exec mysql sh
```

So the service name matters and not what that service is actually running. The image name could be redis or mysql or anything else for that matter.